# Filezilla Server: How to give read and modify files only permission

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, ftp

We want to give FTP access to third party to modify files on a specific folder our server. We will give them access to the specific website's folder only. However, we just want them to read and modify the files and list the directories. We don't want them to create new files in that folder. Is it possible to do so?

In the past, we allowed one third party with Read/Write(files) and List+SubDir(Directories). They uploaded their crazy hacking files and they managed to access our server's Shell prompt, Task Manager and everything. They even installed their software with that Editor.php file on our server. We cannot let it happen again.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which ftp server do you use? Most of the ftp servers offer an option to set such options(e.g. create, delete, lists folder). In vsftpd you have an option like "anon_other_write_enable", which default value is "NO". Read the documentation of your ftp server, there must be such option.

Comment: We are using Filezilla.

Answer (score 2):

In filezilla server control panel go to the users menu and select the user you want to modify. Click "shared folders" in the left menu and click on the directory you want to modify permissions for. Unhceck "Write" and select "append" and only check "list" in the directories permissions.

If you want to edit a user group put the selected users in a group you have created and do the same using the groups option.

Comment: When I removed "Write", "Append" option became disabled. That means they cannot modify or upload a new file.